# Uri vs File vs StringPath in android

Tags: android

Recently I am doing app deals with saving image and loading image on external storage. I am quite confused with `Uri`, `File` and `StringPath`.

For example, when load image from Gallery, it uses `Uri`.

```
if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) { //Browse Gallery is requested
    //Get the path for selected image in Gallery
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    //Access Gallery according to the path
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    loadImage(picturePath);         //load picture according the path
    image_View.setImageBitmap(pic); //Show the selected picture
}
```

Then when decode the image, it uses `StringPath`.

```
private void loadImage(String picturePath) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,options);
    int height_ = options.outHeight;
    int width_ = options.outWidth;
    float ratio = width_/height_;
    int width = 480;
    int height = 480;
    if(width_>height_){
        height = Math.round(width / ratio);
    }else{
        width = Math.round(width*ratio);
    }

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    pic=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,options);
}
```

Then when read byte from file, it uses `File`.

```
File cacheDir = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();
//Form a directory with a file named "pic"
File f = new File(cacheDir, "pic");

try {
    //Prepare output stream that write byte to the directory
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
    //Save the picture to the directory
    pic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So, what is the difference? Is it just different in usage but represent same directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Content URI looks something like:

```
content://media/external/images/media/53
```

The role of `ContentResolver` here is to get you an access to the image based on this URI, you don't need to know the filename or other properties of the file, you just need this URI to access the image.

String Path is the physical address of the image that stored which looks like:

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/myimage.jpg
```

and finally, File is the lowest handler which you need to operate with files. It uses the String Path as argument to create or open the file for read/write.

In your provided example here is the progress:

1- You ask `ContentResolver` to give you the real file path based on the provided URI

2- you load a bitmap file to a `pic` object based on the provided Path

3- you create a file named "pic" and compress the `pic` object to JPG and write to it

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Can u help me to take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466483/how-the-codes-work-for-loading-image-from-gallery-android

Comment: @SamTew I answered your question there

Comment: I did not realise that the person who answer it is you. Thanks a lot

Comment: @SamTew please accept both answers so the questions can be closed